# Eclipse: Create new JavaScript file error

Tags: javascript, eclipse, git

To start of, i made a project in GitHub, imported it into Eclipse (kepler) with Egit, and made it a JavaScript project (with the standard javascript plugin). I worked in this project no problem. I pushed the complete project (including .project files etc. ) into GitHub.

Now, when i import this project on another computer, things go weird. I Imported it with from the GitHub repository with Egit. Then i used the import as existing project, as i uploaded all the project files with it. Now this works great and all, until i want to create a new JavaScript file.

When i do, the new Create a new JavaScript file. window apears, but when i enter a name, the Finish button remains disabled. Also, when i click one of the parent folders i get an nullpointer exception:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here? is it a bug? can't i just import other projects on different pc's? Or is something going wrong with git?

Here is the error log:

Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.wizards.NewJSFileWizardPage.validatePage(NewJSFileWizardPage.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.WizardNewFileCreationPage.handleEvent(WizardNewFileCreationPage.java:676)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.misc.ResourceAndContainerGroup.handleEvent(ResourceAndContainerGroup.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.wmCommandChild(Text.java:2974)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_COMMAND(Control.java:4752)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4614)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4977)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.callWindowProc(Text.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.windowProc(Text.java:2597)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4977)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowTextW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SetWindowText(OS.java:3473)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text.setText(Text.java:2252)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.misc.ContainerSelectionGroup.containerSelectionChanged(ContainerSelectionGroup.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.misc.ContainerSelectionGroup$1.selectionChanged(ContainerSelectionGroup.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2188)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1241)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for more details of the error (or try the Error Log view).

Comment: -edited the logfile into the question. Hardly readable unfortunatly.

Comment: Ah, new information has come to light: If i create a Javascript project out of an exisiting source (so without any github/git things). I have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't occur when i take the next steps:

- import the project with Git (projects files excluded)
- add the project as a general project
- convert it to a JavaScript project.

This has solved my issue, but still i would like to have an answer about what i'm doing wrong with my other method.

Greets, David